# JavaScript button onclick function using DOM and appendChild

Tags: javascript, html, dom, button

I've been trying to make a simple script, but I got stuck. It should work like this:
User click the `ADD button` to add field for creating question, after that, user can click `ADD ONE OPTION button`, in order to create additional blank textareas below the question.

[This is the FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fUms2/5/)

It's not working. Even I make an ADD button work, somehow, the other button stops, I got smth like *Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null.*

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="ADD" onclick="addquestion();" />
<br/><br/>
<div id="below"></div><br/>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
n=1;
function addquestion() {
        var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
        textarea.name = "question[" + n + "]";
        var addone = document.createElement("input");
        addone.type = "button";
        addone.value = "Add one option";
        addone.onclick = "insertbelow("+n+")";
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = n + ". Question:  <br />" + textarea.outerHTML + "<br />" + addone.outerHTML + "<br /><div id=\"radiodown"+n+"\" ></div><hr/><br/>";
        document.getElementById("below").appendChild(div);
        n++;
}

function insertbelow(index) {
    var option = document.createElement("textarea");
    option.name = "rad["+index+"]";
    var optiondiv = document.createElement("div");
    optiondiv.innerHTML = option.outerHTML + "<br/>";
    document.getElementById("radiodown"+index).appendChild(optiondiv);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fUms2/8/)  check out its working fine.

**Updated: Javascript**

```
n=1;
function addquestion() {
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.name = "question[" + n + "]";
    var addone = document.createElement("input");
    addone.type = "button";
    addone.value = "Add one option";
    addone.id="id_"+n;

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = n + ". Question:  <br />" + textarea.outerHTML + "<br />" + addone.outerHTML + "<br /><div id=\"radiodown"+n+"\" ></div><hr/><br/>";
    document.getElementById("below").appendChild(div);

    var btn=document.getElementById("id_"+n);
    if(btn.addEventListener){
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() { insertbelow(this)});    
    } else if(btn.attachEvent){ // IE < 9 :(
        btn.attachEvent('onclick', function() { insertbelow(this)});
    }
    n++;
}

function insertbelow(index) {
    index=index.id.split("_")[1];
    var option = document.createElement("textarea");
    option.name = "rad["+index+"]";
    var optiondiv = document.createElement("div");
    optiondiv.innerHTML = option.outerHTML + "<br/>";
    document.getElementById("radiodown"+index).appendChild(optiondiv);
}
```

Comment: Yea I tried this too, but there is another error here

Comment: Can you update the FIDDLE please. I did this what you said and it's not working again

Comment: Nothing is changed. The button is not working again. Try on my FIDDLE

Comment: Your fiddle has not my code there, and after applying my code, I don't see any error on your fiddle

Comment: I have added fiddle check that out if it solves your problem?

Comment: Like I wrote in my question, I managed to do that also. Obviously I was confusing. The other button is not working. Even in your fiddle. I edited my question and fiddle, no success again

Comment: Yes. You have used EventListnere, thank you very much for the solution. Hope this'll help someone else also.

Comment: my pleasure and I am updating code more to help you for your next function call as well.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to add the onclick event you don't really give the function as handler, but **the result of the execution** of the function (nothing in your case). This can solve your issue:

```
addone.onclick = function() { insertbelow(n) };
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're getting an error because your trying to target a div with the id 'radiodown,' but that doesn't appear to exist.